# is there any simple way to install Apache and php in the Windows7?

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, installation

I want instal the Php in My windows7 PC here i want use Apche webserver is there any simple way to install?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: just a google search would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://www.wampserver.com/en/ (WAMP = Windows Apache MySql Php), it will integrates all you need (php + mysql + apache) including correct configuration

Also you can try http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html (XAMPP).

These packs will help you to install PHP, MySql and Apache without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @michael-swan
i will suggest to go with XAMPP, since you can simply start the XAMPP server and you got apache/php/mysql working.
No need for any installation can be used in a portable drive too.

I am not sure if any such option is available in wamp, but it has easy to handle configs vars

Both the software are bundles of APACHE/PHP/MYSQL package - which are the complete package

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a packaged distribution of Apache, MySQL, and PHP (WAMP) that's all configured and ready to host websites after a short automated install.

Start with this list of WAMPs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

It's the most comprehensive list and will give you some ideas about what's available.

The ones I've seen used most often are [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), and [UniformServer](http://www.uniformserver.com/). There are also commercial ones like [Wamp-Developer](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper).

Try installing 3 of 4 different WAMPs and just trying them out one by one with 1) setting up a new website and 2) installing WordPress as a blog. This will give you a good idea of what works best for you.